# The Best Multilanguage Plugin supporting the FSE

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multi-language

## Background

I have been managing Wordpress sites (and multisite sites) for more than a decade and a half now, and for some reason this is the first time I really had to look into running WordPress in a multilanguage setup.

The project is for a small advisory business where all employees will probably edit some or all of the website at some point, in both the two starter languages.

The most important for me is simplicity of editing, integration into the FSE (as the site has just been rebuilt on top of the twenty twenty-three theme) and Woocommerce support.

Also we want to support having the languages on different domains, ie. sample.de, and sample.us

For each language it is not wanted that the design of the pages change, only the text. However it is expected that there will be lots of small changes all the time, rephrasing something in one language or fixing small mistakes in the other.

## Investigation status

I have looked into the following existing multi language plugins and have found issues with all of them:

- WPML - the Rome of all search results for Wordpress multilanguage.

  1. It is string (or full page) based, which means any small change in the primary language will invalidate all translations (or design changes will only affect one language).
  2. It does not have great interface (i.e. support for the FSE sucks)
- TranslatePress - the pretty one.

  1. It is also string based
- WPGlobal

  1. It does not support FSE
  2. While it is not string (replacement based) it saves the content inside the text and filters it on the output, its a clever trick and could be a fine solution (they could steal some of the ideas from below to support FSE)
  3. If plugin is deactivated all text will be messed up, and show all translations.

## Question

Am I missing something completely obvious (another plugin or setting on the above plugins)

Answer (score 0):

## Proposed solution - a new plugin

A new plugin built around the blocks and possibilities of the block editor. Having translations done within the FSE / Block Editor. The description below will focus on the translations of the Block items, because solving non-block based items is probably really easy since all multilanguage plugins already do it.

### Technical overview

- Block attributes will contain references to translations
- Translations will contain the full block content and it will be the choice of the editor if they want to translate blocks with children or only the lowest level.
- When rendering blocks the correct translated item will be fetched from the translation table.
- In order to speed things up we should hook into a general page hook just before individual block rendering, fetch all block translate ids, get all translations in a single query (for the currently selected language), store them in a memory variable and use that variable when rendering the blocks - that will cause only a single extra SQL lookup per page/post
- This will also mean if the plugin is deactivated all content will continue to work without any cleaning necessary

### Sample block

Block content

```html
<!-- wp:paragraph {"translation":{"id": "idofdatabaseitem", "temp" : { "currentlanguage": "de", "pageid": 123}}} -->
<p class="_text_highlighted">This is the currently displayed language</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

### Issues that needs to be addressed

- We must hook the onload/onpublish/onsave of the FSE to make sure as possible that the stored content of a post is the base language (for page rendering it should not matter as we will just get the content from the database) however we want to make sure that the editor has a consistent content.
- We must hook the FSE in order to load the correct block content for the selected editing language. It is possible to hook into existing block editors like this (https://mariecomet.fr/en/2021/12/14/adding-options-controls-existing-gutenberg-block/)
- We must hook copy/paste for copy paste operations in the same page as we want to duplicate translations and not link them to the old ones
- We must hook copy/paste or page duplicate or maybe better make sure to keep track of which page ID a translated block belongs to (so in the translations table keep ID, page_ID, content) so we can detect when a block is a copy from another page and we can duplicate the translations.

## Next Step

- Do you think this is possible?
- Should we do this together?
- Other questions or comments?

Answer (score 0):

You have already looked into some of the most popular multilingual plugins for WordPress, and you have rightly pointed out some of their limitations. Here are a few more options you could consider:

Polylang: This is a popular multilingual plugin that has been around for a long time. It allows you to create a multilingual website with posts, pages, custom post types, and taxonomies. You can translate the content or have separate content for each language. Polylang also supports WooCommerce, and you can have different currencies and prices for each language. It has a user-friendly interface, and it is compatible with the block editor (Gutenberg). Polylang also allows you to use different domains for each language.

Weglot: Weglot is a cloud-based multilingual plugin that uses machine translation to translate your website. It is easy to set up, and you can have a multilingual website in a matter of minutes. Weglot also supports WooCommerce, and you can have different currencies and prices for each language. You can translate the content manually, edit the machine translation, or hire professional translators. Weglot has a user-friendly interface and works well with the block editor (Gutenberg). It also allows you to use different domains for each language.

MultilingualPress: This is another popular multilingual plugin that allows you to create a multilingual website with separate content for each language. MultilingualPress uses a network of WordPress installations to create a multilingual website, which means that each language has its own WordPress site. This allows you to have complete control over the content for each language. MultilingualPress also supports WooCommerce, and you can have different currencies and prices for each language. It has a user-friendly interface and is compatible with the block editor (Gutenberg). MultilingualPress also allows you to use different domains for each language.

It's important to note that all of these plugins have their pros and cons, and you should choose the one that best fits your needs and preferences. It's also important to thoroughly test any multilingual plugin before using it on a live site to make sure it meets your requirements.